# Replaced axle and now clunking in back

Tags: hub, axle, quick-release, cones

I finally got a rear axle replaced, and all new cones on a new axle... I assembled it back together with 7 or 8 of the bearings in on each side and some grease, put it all back together, put the freewheel cogs on (how did I even try it without the freewheel remover before...) and wheel was spinning fine without play left/right (well, maybe 1mm). The gears all shift too.

When I ride the bike I am often hearing a clunking in the rear though. When I just spin the crank or wheel when the bike is stopped It seems I cannot get it to happen. The back wheel feels pretty good. What should I look at for adjusting this? It happens when freewheeling and when pedaling and I don't see anything obviously tapping or loose.

Comment: Is the axle tightly fastened to the frame?  Is the chain skipping?  Do you feel anything when it goes "clunk"?

Comment: It is tightly fastened and it doesn't seem to skip. It just makes a clunking noise in back. Only when riding, not when testing it out or spinning the wheel.

Comment: Do you have a fender on the rear?  Is it perhaps catching the tire?

Comment: No fender. It feels normal but clinking almost like bearings are falling around somewhere... but only when riding it.

Comment: Did you drop some bearings inside the hub while rebuilding it?

Comment: I don't think so. it feels quite smooth and spins and spins when I move it while not riding.

Comment: You could have lost one or two balls inside without obviously compromising the overall "bearingness" of the wheel (though being short bearings will cause increase wear on the cones and cups).  And the balls would tend to stick to the inside of the hub (due to grease in there) until jarred loose by rough pavement.

Comment: 1mm axial play of the axle is far too much. You should adjust the cones so that all play is *just* removed, without any binding of the bearings.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus That seems to be the answer, just opened it up, put a little more grease in and tightened it up just a tad more. A quick test ride sounded okay.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure the outer races of the hub free of pits and corrosion. The wheel may feel smooth when spinning it off the bike, but the roughness may appear only when the bearing is loaded.